# Boolean value is not saving to the state. Using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am building an ecommerce site, and am adding admin function to edit current users. The default value for my isSeller and isAdmin variables is set to false. When I try to change it to true, it works fine, but I am unable to change it back to false. Ive tried changing the default to true and creating a new user and changing it to false, but that also did not work. Here is some of my code.
https://github.com/amkreiner/buyitallonline

User Edit Screen

```
export default function UserEditScreen(props) {
  const userId = props.match.params.id;
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [isSeller, setIsSeller] = useState(false);
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { loading, error, user } = userDetails;

  const userUpdate = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdate);
  const {
    loading: loadingUpdate,
    error: errorUpdate,
    success: successUpdate,
  } = userUpdate;

  const stringToBoolean = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    if (value && typeof value === "string") {
      if (value.toLowerCase() === "yes") return true;
      if (value.toLowerCase() === "no") return false;
    }
    return value;
  };

  const changeValue = (value) => {
    if (value === true) {
      return "yes";
    }
    if (value === false) {
      return "no";
    }
    return value;
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (successUpdate) {
      dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_RESET });
      props.history.push("/userlist");
    }
    if (!user) {
      dispatch(detailsUser(userId));
    } else {
      setName(user.name);
      setEmail(user.email);
      setIsSeller(user.isSeller);
      setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin);
    }
  }, [dispatch, props.history, successUpdate, user, userId]);


  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //dispatch update user
    console.log(`isSeller:${isSeller}`);
    console.log(`isAdmin:${isAdmin}`);
    dispatch(updateUser({ _id: userId, name, email, isSeller, isAdmin }));
  };
```

...

```
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="isSeller">Is Seller</label>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setIsSeller(stringToBoolean(e.target.value))}
        id="isSeller"
        value={changeValue(isSeller)}
      >
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="isAdmin">Is Admin</label>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setIsAdmin(stringToBoolean(e.target.value))}
        id="isAdmin"
        value={changeValue(isAdmin)}
      >
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Reducer

```
export const userUpdateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_UPDATE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true };
    case USER_UPDATE_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_UPDATE_RESET:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

User Actions

```
export const updateUser = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_REQUEST, payload: user });
  const {
    userSignin: { userInfo },
  } = getState();
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.put(`/api/users/${user._id}`, user, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
    });
    dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_FAIL, payload: message });
  }
};
```

Model

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    isSeller: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

Router

```
userRouter.put(
  "/:id",
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (user) {
      user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
      user.isSeller = req.body.isSeller || user.isSeller;
      user.isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin || user.isAdmin;
      const updatedUser = await user.save();
      res.send({ message: "User Updated", user: updatedUser });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not Found" });
    }
  })
);
```

If you need anything else, my updated repository can be found at https://github.com/amkreiner/buyitallonline

Comment: Seems you don't actually update your redux state with either of the `USER_UPDATE_REQUEST` or `USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS` actions. Did you mean to  process those action payloads in the reducer? Presumably those have the updated values?

Comment: I am still fairly new to redux and am not sure exactly what I am accomplishing here. I fixed the problem by changing a couple lines in my userRouter to this:     
      user.isSeller = req.body.isSeller;
      user.isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;                                                                     After I looked at what was happening here, it looks like I am adding the new user to my state in userList, using that user to update my database, and then deleting the user from the store in userList when I reset. Anyone more experienced feel free to correct me on what is happening

Comment: Oh, I see, you're not even storing user data in your redux state, that is all just managing fetching indication/error status. Everything else occurs on the server/DB side. So, which state isn't updating boolean values? Local component state? Redux state? Backend state?

Comment: It was only when trying to update the values from true to false that is wasn't changing the value. It is updating my backend state (mongodb database). I am not keeping any of the user data in the state in this case because it is an admin user editing another user, so I won't need the state data for the other user for any other actions, which is why I am deleting it from the state following a successful update.

Comment: Changing user.isSeller = req.body.isSeller || user.isSeller; to user.isSeller = req.body.isSeller and the same for isAdmin in my router fixed the issue for me